# Sketch the solid in the first octant bounded by the graphs of the equation and find its volume.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, volume

Given $$2x + y + z = 4 \ \ x = 0,\  y = 0,\  z = 0$$
This is a plane in the first quadrant so I need to set up the triple integral and solve in order to get the area but I am not sure how to determine the bounds of each integral. This is what I have:

$$ \int_0^1\int_0^1\int_0^2 2x + y + z \ dx \ dy \ dz$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hints**: substitute in the plane's equation to find its intersection points with the coordinate planes

$$\begin{cases}y=z=0\implies2x=4\implies x=2\\{}\\x=z=0\implies y=4\\{}\\x=y=0\implies z=4\end{cases}$$

Thus, on the $\;xy\,-$ plane we have $\;0\le x\le 2\;$ while $\;2x+y=4\implies y=-2x+4\;$ ...

Comment: would that make it 0 to 2, 0 to 4 and 0 to 4 for the bounds ?

Comment: @DougRay No, because then you'd be evaluating over a *box*. Try to sketch a diagram: the plane makes a "triangle-like" figure over the first octant, which in fact is a 3-dimensional triangular prism whose intersection points with the axis are $\;(2,0,0),\,(0,4,0),\,(0,0,4)\;$ , but the figure whose volume you want is, on the $\;xy-$ plane, over the triangle $\;0\le x\le 2\,,\,0\le y\le-2x+4\;$ , and up towards the $\;z-axis\;$ between $\;0\le z\le 4-2x-y\;$ .